# I used SpringApplicationBuilder to open two contexts and packaged them through graalvm, but encountered a problem

Tags: graalvm

I used SpringApplicationBuilder to open two contexts and packaged them through graalvm, but encountered a problemI used SpringApplicationBuilder to start two contexts, and the ports are different. One web is 8080, and one api is 8081. I can run it normally through the jar package, but after packaging it into an executable program through graalvm, the Web application could not be started as there was no org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory bean defined in the context.this is my error:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:
Web application could not be started as there was no org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory bean defined in the context.
Action:
Check your application's dependencies for a supported servlet web server.
Check the configured web application type.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplicationBuilder(MainContextConfiguration::class.java)
        .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
        .child(ApiApp::class.java)
        .web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET)
        .sibling(WebApp::class.java)
        .web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET)
        .run(*args)
}
```

I expect that the code packaged by graalvm can run like a jar package